# How can I check apache modules version?

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver, debian, module

How do I get versions of apache modules on debian?

I can get loaded modules list by apache2ctl -M - but how do I get their version numbers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
apt-cache show libapache2-mod-foobar | grep Version
```

Comment: Note though that if you installed the module using `apxs` or some other method, this won't give you the installed version, but rather the version in the repositories.

Comment: Is there a way to find in fedora-like OS? I'm using oracle linux

Answer (score 11):

```
$ strings /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_pagespeed.so \
    | grep "mod_pagespeed/[0-9]\.[0-9]"
mod_pagespeed/w.x.y.z
```

Find more at http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/find-out-apache-module-version.html

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-foobar
```