# Finding installed apache module versions in CentOS/RHEL

Tags: apache, apache2, centos, rhel

I found a similar question about this but aimed at Debian [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230733/how-can-i-check-apache-modules-version).

However since I don't have apt-cache it doesn't help me. Running:

```
    httpd -M
```

Gives me a list of all the installed modules but not their versions. My colleague has just pointed out that you can use:

```
    yum info mod_dav_svn.x86_64
```

This returns the installed version and the one available via Yum, however, if I use httpd -M it lists the names like:

mod_proxy_http.so

Is there any easy way to match up the installed modules file name (i.e. x86_64 i386) so I can check each module, or even better does anyone know of a way to output this info for all modules at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear for me what you exactly want to know or achieve, but for me something like this seems to work:

> cd /usr/lib/httpd/modules/
>   file *.so

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in CentOS Release 6.4 - but this directory has those same files: /etc/httpd/modules

Answer (score 4):

You can use yum to get the version of apache's modules:

```
yum info mod_fcgid
```

Answer (score 0):

## List of installed Apache modules:

```
yum list installed mod_*
```

or

```
rpm -qa mod_*
```

---

#### Formatted output "PackageName-Version-Release.Arch":

```
yum list installed mod_* | awk '/mod_.*/ { split($1,a,"."); print a[1] "-" $2 "." a[2] }'
```

or

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n" mod_*
```